# data between dates displays all heads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have three feilds Start Date  End Date HeadName   i looking to search data between dates which i am able to get but headname is not filtered.It displays all results

```
Sno HeadName    Date    Amount  BillNo  BillDate    PaymentMode BankName    ChequeNo    Remarks Center
1   8   2013-10-18  0   0   2013-10-26  Select      0       Bhopal
2   3   2013-10-20  0   0   2013-10-20  Select      0       0
```

Now this headname should be only 8 and 3 should not display
My code is

```
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM CashbookMaster WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$stop_time'"  );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
```

Comment: Have you var_dump both start and stop to make sure they are what you think they are. Also is the Date field a date field or a dateTime field or something else?

Comment: Instead of doing `SELECT *` you should be limiting it to the actual columns, i.e.: `SELECT HeadName, Date FROM CashbookMaster etc.`

Comment: @Casey date feild is date type

Comment: @Fred-ii-hi can u explain a bit more

Comment: @Fred-ii-Can u please write it down for me

Comment: @Fred-ii- i selected as u said but shows blank results.i want to display all results in that particulr head

Comment: @Fred-ii- He's not trying to limit to one, this is just an example, it could just as easily be 30 results

Comment: @user2896851 IT has to be in the variables. Your sql is correct. var_dump and start and end make sure they are in sql format Y-m-d and in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to also filter on HeadName, you would need to add it to the WHERE clause

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM CashbookMaster WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$stop_time' AND HeadName = 8"  );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
```